# Erlang Socket at OS Level

Tags: linux, erlang, elixir, freebsd, erlang-otp

I am so confused about multi-thread networking. Since a Socket is an OS Level structure, handling sockets at Erlang BEAM VM level has an equivalent at OS Level, and there are multi options to handle parallel connections by OS-Threads (select, poll, epoll,....) and that depends of the OS but what i can't understand and I searched a lot about without any answer is: If we have 4 **Parallel** Erlang processes listen to accept connection on one Socket, what is the equivalent at OS Level? 4 waiting **Parallel** OS-Threads? N Parallel  OS-Thread?

Comment: You've recently asked multiple variations of essentially the same question. If you're looking for details of the internals of the Erlang virtual machine, my advice is to read [The Beam Book](https://github.com/happi/theBeamBook).

Comment: Thank you for help, i think that's what i search

Comment: sorry but the socket and network chapter is missing

Comment: Yes, that's a bit unfortunate. But you can still use the book to learn more about Erlang VM schedulers. I also encourage you to ask questions on [Erlang Slack](https://erlef.org/slack-invite/erlanger) and even [build your own debuggable Erlang runtime](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Advanced-configuration-and-build-of-ErlangOTP_Building_How-to-Build-a-Debug-Enabled-Erlang-RunTime-System) so you can use a debugger to see what the schedulers are doing.

Comment: all i know about debuggers is that debug your program, it doesn't show internal management, i will try with the Erlang Slack thank you for the link

Answer (score 1):

It's a difficult correspondence to draw.  Your suggestion 4 Parallel threads is probably the closest equivalent.  Things get a bit harder to pin down because a kernel thread will likely take up more system resources than each process.  Threads typically share memory space while there is memory protection between processes.  So it depends on how far you want to take the  simile, but basically there will be 4 separate lines of processing blocked on I/O.